# Semantic UI - Accordion not expanding in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, semantic-ui

I am trying to add a [semantic-ui accordion](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion.html#/usage) into my Angular application, however when i add it onto the page, it is not 'clickable'.

I am aware, that I am supposed to initialize the accordion, but frankly as a begginer to Angular and typescript I am not quite sure where exactly I am supposed to put the init script. I tried putting it into the html file, but that did not do anything.

The init function should be following:

```
$('.ui.accordion')
  .accordion()
```

Comment: I don't think, that using this library is good in Angular. You can choose something with better Angular support, like Bootstrap.

Comment: https://edcarroll.github.io/ng2-semantic-ui/#/modules/accordion for angular version of semantic (not official) that replaces jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Jquery Function, If you want to use An Accordion with Angular I suggest you use  [n2-semantic-ui](https://edcarroll.github.io/ng2-semantic-ui/#/modules/accordion) as @penleychan suggested or better [ngBootstrap Accordion](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/accordion-basic.ts) or [material design expansion](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview)